# How to pickle a callback chain

Tags: python, twisted, pickle, deferred

I have a user-defined state machine in Twisted. The user can define handlers for different state changes, which I implement by using a Twisted deferred that I let them add callbacks to. Whenever I move from one state to another, I simply fire the appropriate deferred.

One of the project requirements is the ability to save this state machine to disk, along with all its callbacks. I thought I could simply pickle the state machine and I'd be done, but I get a PickleError when I try to serialize user-defined functions.

Does anybody know of a way to serialize functions? The error is reproduced in the below code sample:

```
import pickle
from twisted.internet.utils import defer

def foo(*args):
  def bar():
    print args
  return bar

d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(foo("Hello", "world"))
pickle.dumps(d)
```

This last line gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 1366, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 615, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function bar at 0xb753fe2c>: it's not found as __main__.bar
```

Are there any solutions to this? Maybe I need to restrict the types of functions that users can add as callbacks?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: I guess there are two separate questions here: (1) is how to store the callback chain - store them separately, as Jean-Paul suggested - and (2) is how to store the callbacks themselves - use functors, like vz0 suggests. How do I accept both of your answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to pickle Deferreds.  It's not supported by Twisted.  Even if you manage to construct something that seems to work (and it's not *entirely* impossible), a later release of Twisted might break all of your saved state.

Deferreds are for controlling the flow of events through your code.  They're not for storing application state.  If you want to persist your application state, separate it from any Deferreds and serialize **just** it.

When you do this, you probably also want to avoid using pickle for the serialization format.  Pickle is not a good way to store data.  It is a high complex format which is very sensitive to changes in Python versions and library versions.  It has no means to define a schema, so you can never really be sure what you're serializing or what you have serialized.  It is very difficult to inspect a pickle separately from loading it, so if it ever breaks (as it will if you decide to rename a class which you have pickled instances of), recovering the data is a major hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the foo/bar functions with a callable class instance:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def __call__(self):
        print self.args

d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(foo("Hello", "world"))
pickle.dumps(d)
```

Comment: Presumably, the idea of pickling a function is so that you can close your program or transfer the pickled object and expect the function to be called elsewhere. This won't work because function addresses are determined at run-time. It might work for several consecutive runs of the program, but it isn't safe.

Comment: Took my downvote away because I think I realized that you're talking about a functor. +1, now, although this type of callback can cause design problems if you're trying to be very OOP and typesafe. :)

Comment: @San Jacinto: Yes, it works. Pickle Documentation clearly states what can and can not be pickled. http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: @vz0 Yes, I was thinking you had intended to pass the function object into the functor and use it somehow later to call the function. Obviously, this was not your intent now that I see it again. Your example really did not lend itself well to this distinction.

Comment: Using a callable instance doesn't particularly help here.  You could also use a bound method, or a global function.  The important point is that the resultant object is made entirely of globally-addressable code objects, not inner functions.  But see Jean-Paul's answer for the real solution - don't pickle `Deferred`s.

Comment: @San Jacinto: Functions are not pickled by their address; that's not how it works at all.  They are pickled and loaded by their qualified name.  Look at the string that comes out of 'def foo(): pass; from cPickle import dumps; dumps(foo)' in an interactive interpreter; no runtime-determined memory address in there.

Comment: I inspected the output of dumps(), and it represents the function by module & name. Will loads() auto-import the module, as long as it's in the path? Or do I need to have the user pre-import the module in which their code is defined?

Comment: loads() will in fact auto-import the module, but you can control how those names are looked up by subclassing Unpickler and overriding load_global.  http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#subclassing-unpicklers